# Sonar branch analysis: calculate and show coverage

Tags: sonarqube

We are using the new branch analysis feature with sonar 6.7.5:

```
./gradlew -Dsonar.branch.name=$branchName clean build sonarqube
```

For coverage analysis we use:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

The problem is that the issues of the branches are shown but not the coverage of the branch. So if we merge into master we never know if the coverage is high enough to pass the quality gate. Is there a possibility to show the coverage for a specific branch?

In the sonarqube project dashboard the coverage of the master branch is shown just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have same issue. seems like only main branch/master shows coverage, branch analysis only display issues. trying to figure out of this is config issue, or expected behaviour.

Actually I think I have found the reason.
Coverage is available only for long-lived branches. 
This is fixed in later version of sonar.

[SonarQube Coverage for Branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450583/sonarqube-coverage-for-branch)

seems like 
Code coverage is available on short-lived branches and PRs in 7.4. Duplication will be available in 7.5.